# Azure Archive creating a big nested file structure

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I just want the root of the zip file to be the root of my content, do not include all the other none needed nested folders.

**Zip Created**

[image: zip created]

**Archive settings**
[image: archive settings]

**EDIT**
I have ASP.NET Web forms project that i created a Build pipe for the project, publish artifact is created, then  for that particular build i went to releases, created a release, picked the artifact from the previous build pipeline and then added a archive task.

What else can i show you/tell you about that will help?

Comment: Where you use this Archive task, in the release pipeline or build pipeline? I have seen the source of the Archive task is output of the web App publish, so, would you please share some more info about what you are archiving now?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT i added more notes to the OP, I am really trying to wrap my head around this whole pipleline thing. I simply want to do the following. 1. setup a pipeline for the aspnet project, when any dev commits any code (git), there is a pipelines that makes sure it builds, then when we are ready to create a release, we just either based on that pipeline or another for us to create a zip file that we can ftp (another task) to send it to our server so we can deploy it

Comment: Sorry for reply later, I just came back from my vacation and I will check your updates as soon as possible.